# How do I perform a continuous check on andorid of the returned value of another class?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to perform a check in an android thread to check the returned value of a method in another class. Here is my code so far:

```
public class HelloWorldAndroid extends AndroidApplication {

    private MyGame myGame;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            **********Other lines Omitted***********

    myGame = new MyGame(false, 30, new AndroidLeaderboard());


            //check to see if the game is over
    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (myGame.gameOver()) {


                //if the game is over go to another screen
                startActivity(new Intent(HelloWorldAndroid.this, MainActivity.class));

            }
        }

    });
            background.start();
      }
```

Ive tried to implement this with a handler but it just doesn't perform the check so when the value is true it still runs. Does anyone know how I can perform the check `myGame.gameOver() = true` continuously throughout the running of this thread (so I can move on to a different activity).

Been racking my brains for days on this one and still have nothing :S 
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you post MyGame class code?.

Answer (score 4):

Why not create some kind of Listener (interface) ?

Small and basic example,

```
myGame = new MyGame(false, 30, new AndroidLeaderboard());
myGame.setGameOverListener(this);
```

**Note:** You don't need a `setGameOverListener` method, you could also change your constructor to have a listener argument.

The listener would look like this:

```
interface GameOverListener {
    abstract public void notifyGameOver();
}
```

And create a method in side you MyGame object:

```
setGameOverListener(GameOverListener gol){
    this.gol = gol;
}
```

And your Activity would implement that listener, and in the `notifyGameOver()` method you would open the activity.

Like this:

```
public void notifyGameOver(){
    startActivity(new Intent(HelloWorldAndroid.this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

To notify that your game is over just let your MyGame object call the `notifyGameOver()` method:

```
gol.notifyGameOver();
```

Comment: I might add that the typical android/java convention would be `onGameOver()` as opposed to `notifyGameOver()`, but of course choose what works for you

Answer (score 3):

This seems like very bad design to me. Instead, I would recommend creating an interface `OnGameOverListener` that has one method, `onGameOver()`. The `MyGame` class has an instance of this interface that clients can set. Then, when the `MyGame` class decides the game is over, it can call `onGameOver()`

Look at the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)