# Android - Timer function and alertDialog

Tags: android, timer, popup, android-alertdialog

I created a game with timer, I am trying to make that when the timer is end the player will see alert popup or any kind of pop up that say "level complete", your points are xxx and a button for next level. I tried something but the time over but no popup. 
any idea?

**Time Class: work fine.**

public class Time {

```
private String time;
private boolean isDone;

public Time() {
    super();
    isDone=false;
}

CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds = seconds % 60;
    String tempSec=Integer.toString(seconds);
    if (tempSec.length()==1){
        tempSec="0"+tempSec;
    }
    time="Time Left: " + minutes + ":"+tempSec;
 }

 public void onFinish() {
    setDone(true);
}

}.start();
```

**This is the Activity class:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    club=new Club();
    clubView = new ClubView(this, club);
    mole=new Mole();
    stageView=new StageView(this);
    moleView=new MoleView(this,mole);
    pointsView=new PointsView(this);

    time=new Time();
    timerView=new TimerView(this, time);

    allViews=new AllViews(this);
    allViews.setViews(stageView, moleView, pointsView, timerView,clubView);

    setContentView(allViews);
    allViews.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener)this);

    if (timerView.getTime().isDone()){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Level Complete");
        builder.setMessage("your score is"+pointsView.getPoint());
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the timer takes some while to run out, and you are checking just once if the timer is done:

```
if (timerView.getTime().isDone()){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Level Complete");
    builder.setMessage("your score is"+pointsView.getPoint());
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

A better options would be to create some kind of loop, but this is **forbidden**! Because you would block the main thread.

The next option you have is to create some kind of listener. The listener will do some kind of callback to your activity to tell "i'm done". This is often done using interfaces,

Small Example:

```
public class Time {

    private String time;
    private boolean isDone;
    private TimerCallback timerCallback;

    public Time(TimerCallback t) {
        this.timerCallback = t;
        isDone = false;
    }

    public interface TimerCallback {
        abstract void onTimerDone();
    }

    CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            String tempSec = Integer.toString(seconds);
            if (tempSec.length() == 1) {
                tempSec = "0" + tempSec;
            }
            time = "Time Left: " + minutes + ":" + tempSec;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            setDone(true);
            timerCallback.onTimerDone();
        }

    }.start();

}
```

And your activity would look like this:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements TimerCallback {
//I have now clue how your activity is named but it's just an example!

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        club = new Club();
        clubView = new ClubView(this, club);
        mole = new Mole();
        stageView = new StageView(this);
        moleView = new MoleView(this, mole);
        pointsView = new PointsView(this);

        //Because we are implementing the TimerCallback interface "this" is a valid argument
        //this can be cast to TimerCallback:  "(TimerCallback) this"
        time = new Time(this);
        timerView = new TimerView(this, time);

        allViews = new AllViews(this);
        allViews.setViews(stageView, moleView, pointsView, timerView, clubView);

        setContentView(allViews);
        allViews.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener) this);


    }

    //We must add this method, because we have implemented the TimerCallback interface!
    public void onTimerDone(){
        //You could remove the isDone check because it is not really necessary
        if (timerView.getTime().isDone()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Level Complete");
            builder.setMessage("your score is" + pointsView.getPoint());
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

I have posted a very similar answer here, but in this question there is no timer but some kind of a "gameover" event.
[How do I perform a continuous check on andorid of the returned value of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941654/how-do-i-perform-a-continuous-check-on-andorid-of-the-returned-value-of-another/12941725)

And a wiki link about the listener pattern, or observer pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Rolf

Comment: Thanks, Excelent solution, any advise on adding button to the alert?

Comment: Take a look here, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
 setPositiveButton and Negative could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) to run a scheduled action. Examples are [here](http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/) and [here](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).